# how to set up /configure test cases before triggering in jenkins

Tags: jenkins

After the build is passed for source code, some .jar files are created.
Those jar files have to be put in specific path before triggering relevant testcases in Jenkins.

In a short,
How to configure/set up the test cases after the successful build and before triggering them in Jenkins?

Comment: Can you not put your tests as a separate job, then pass the tests and the jars as artefacts between the two jobs?

Answer (score 0):

Have 1 job to build your code. 
Add a post exec command to this job to move the jar files to the correct path

After this build job is finished have it trigger a second job that does only the tests.